# How to modify menu-block template with preprocessor in theming level

Tags: 8, hooks, theming

I am trying to modify menu block that locates in primary region with preprocessor in theme level but I don't think I will be able to accomplish without a lead or advice.

So this image is what I need to get, so "News","White Papers" and "Partners" are sub pages and sub menu items of /resource page. On "News" I just want to feed that news category(which taxonomy terms) and dates. (I am not worried about style of the block right now) [image: unstyled menu]

This is what I got so far:

[image]

I did this many times in Drupal 7 but I am pretty new to 8.